# Is there a way to use emoji with Cairo's "toy" text API?

Tags: ruby, emoji, cairo

Is there any font or technique I can use with Cairo (via Ruby bindings) to draw text containing emoji? Everything I've read says "use Pango for real text handling" but Cairo does everything else I need so I'm hoping there's a way to avoid adding that as a dependency.

Here's a simplified version of the dynamic Open Graph images I'm trying to make:

```
require 'cairo'

# Create a new image surface based on recommended OpenGraph dimensions
width = 1_200
height = 630
surface = Cairo::ImageSurface.new(width, height)

# Create a Cairo Context for the surface
cr = Cairo::Context.new(surface)

# Apply a background colour to the whole thing (almost white)
cr.set_source_rgb(0.95, 0.95, 0.95)
cr.paint

# Add a heading
heading = "Hi! "
cr.set_source_rgb(0.31, 0.21, 0.27)
cr.select_font_face("Sans", Cairo::FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, Cairo::FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
cr.set_font_size(100.0)
extents = cr.text_extents(heading)
centred_text_left_edge = width / 2 - extents.width / 2
cr.move_to(centred_text_left_edge, 130)
cr.show_text(heading)

# Write the image surface to a PNG file
surface.write_to_png("emoji-test-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z')}.png")
```

Unfortunately the emoji gets rendered as a rectangle (running on macOS, might be different on other platforms):

[image: Generated image contains a square instead of the waving hand emoji]

Can I use a custom font or is there some other technique that will get the emoji to display?

It seems the "correct" option is to use Pango, but is that advice still current and applicable to Ruby? I couldn't get the Pango gem to install on my M1 Mac and even if I could, after much searching the only reference I can find to using Pango with Cairo from Ruby is [a very old sample script that's no longer included in the Pango distibution](https://github.com/fukuchi/ruby-gnome2/blob/493c474e630745dcc193b8fed0dad563f3847077/pango/sample/pango_cairo.rb).

Failing that I guess I'll have to save the emoji as images and paint them onto the Surface/Context. This is feasible for me because I only want to use 3 specific emoji but it's not scalable for including arbitrary emoji.

Comment: Your emoji seems to be unicode codepoint _U+1F44B_ and I'm pretty sure that your program can handle this. However you don't say **how** you are going to "display" this output. Does the program which displays it include a font which contains definitions for U+1F44B?

Comment: Probably should have been a bit clearer. I'm trying to make dynamic OpenGraph images (think Social Media previews when you share a link) so I'm rendering the image as a PNG with `surface.write_to_png`

Comment: Never worked with `Cairo`, but a wild guess is that the font definition file which you select with `cr.select_font_face` does not contain a definition for U+1F44B. Is there a way to specify in Cairo some "fall-back"-font for the case that an UTF8 character can't be found in the selected font?

Comment: Cairo really does not want to get into the business of font selection. Yes, there is a way to get fallback fonts. They way to do that is to the font selection yourself. This means that instead of `cairo_show_text()` you get to play with scaled fonts and APIs like `cairo_show_glyphs()`. If you do not want to implement the necessary code yourself, you could use some existing implementation. For example, Pango does font selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will happily accept another answer if someone else has a better solution but I ended up falling back to painting on a PNG of an emoji. Read to the end for the downsides to this approach.

First I saved a 96x96 pixel PNG of the emojis I wanted to use (e.g. `wave.png`). Then I painted them on to the surface. Here's a POC:

```
require 'cairo'

# Create a new image surface based on recommended OpenGraph dimensions
width = 1_200
height = 630
surface = Cairo::ImageSurface.new(width, height)

# Create a Cairo Context for the surface
cr = Cairo::Context.new(surface)

# Apply a background colour to the whole thing (almost white)
cr.set_source_rgb(0.95, 0.95, 0.95)
cr.paint

# Set up the heading
string = "Hi!"
cr.set_source_rgb(0.31, 0.21, 0.27)
cr.select_font_face("Sans", Cairo::FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, Cairo::FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
cr.set_font_size(100.0)
text_box = cr.text_extents(string)

# Set up the emoji image
image = Cairo::ImageSurface.from_png("wave.png")

# Position the text in the centre (taking into account the image width)
horizontal_gap = 20 # trial and error
top_of_text = 130 # trial and error
line_width = text_box.width + image.width + horizontal_gap
text_left_edge = (width - line_width) / 2 # centred on page
cr.move_to(text_left_edge, top_of_text)
cr.show_text(string)

# Position the image next to the text
top_of_image = top_of_text - 85 # trial and error
image_left_edge = text_left_edge + text_box.width + horizontal_gap
cr.set_source(image, image_left_edge, top_of_image)
cr.paint

# Write the image surface to a PNG file
surface.write_to_png("emoji-test.png")
```

This generates my OpenGraph image with text and an emoji:
[image: Sample Open Graph image with the word Hi and a waving hand emoji]

The downsides to this approach are:

- You need to create each emoji PNG individually
- Scaling images independently proved difficult for me (I'm also painting a logo onto the surface) so I had to make the PNGs the exact size I wanted them displayed
- It took a lot of trial and error to get text and images positioned satisfactorily
- Copyright risks... I am not a lawyer but I'm pretty sure can't legally use images of Apple's (or Microsoft's or Google's) emoji without permission:

  - [JoyPixels](https://joypixels.com/licenses/pricing) has licensable emoji that can be used in commercial settings and for client work
  - [Twitter Emoji (Twemoji)](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) are available under Creative Commons
  - You could use an [open source icon set](https://icon-sets.iconify.design) instead of emojis